# Fabricjs: when editing text that is reversed with flipX the individual characters remain flipped; editing isn't very usable

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Upon editing a Fabricjs IText with `flipX = true`, why does the entire string get un-flipped but each character remains flipped?  And editing is not really usable.  Are there other properties or something I should be using to help it work better?

This creates a Fabricjs IText and reverses the string:

```
var txt = "Reverse string";
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var text = new fabric.IText(txt, { 
    left: 20, 
    top: 30, 
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    fontSize: 40,
    flipX: true
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);
canvas.renderAll();
```

...as expected:

[image]

But when you click in the IText to edit it, it changes to this with the whole string in order but the individual characters remain flipped:

[image]

...and the left key moves the cursor right and vice versa.  This would make more sense if the whole string was flipped, but it isn't now.  Is this just the current state of the code?  Are there any workarounds?

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/f282oo2w/

Comment: ...just for my own curiosity , what do you need this feature?

Comment: for applying to inside of glass window but to be readable from the outside

Answer (score 2):

Because you flip the string object not the characters.

If you want to flip the characters you need to draw a `fabricjs.Group`

```
for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    left += 25;

    character = new fabric.IText(txt[i], {    
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        fontSize: 40,
        flipX: true,
        left: left
    });

    string.push(character);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f282oo2w/8/

Comment: I *don't want* to flip the characters--Fabric.js is wrongly (I believe) leaving the characters flipped the characters when it goes into edit mode.  It is correct when I render the IText.  What I want is to display the string flipped when not in edit mode, but normal (nothing flipped) when editing.

Comment: understand, let me check